# Undefined reference on old project compilation

Tags: c++, compilation, sfml, undefined-reference

I've got some trouble compiling an old project.
I've succeed to solve some failures but some still remain.

```
./lib/libgdl_gl-2012.4/lib/libgdl_gl.so: undefined reference to `sf::Unicode::Text::Text(std::string const&)'

//usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.so.1.6: undefined reference to `sf::Unicode::Text::operator std::basic_string<unsigned int, std::char_traits<unsigned int>, std::allocator<unsigned int> > const&() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm using those flags: `-I ./lib/libgdl_gl-2012.4/include -L ./lib/libgdl_gl-2012.4/lib -lpthread -Wl,--rpath=./lib/libgdl_gl-2012.4/lib -lsfml-audio -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-system -lgdl_gl -lGL -lGLU -Wall -W -Werror -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`

Help ?

Comment: Whatever `gdl_gl` is, it seems to link to a different version of `sfml-system`, which might also cause the follow up error regarding `sfml-graphics`.

Comment: I already explored this way but the project required sfml 1.6, it solved most of my errors except those two last so I'm using the right version of sfml.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem, it was the libsfml.
The one I had wasn't properly compiled.

It's working now ;)